# Convert date only to string

Tags: c#, asp.net

In my website when a user logs in he sees a 'My Account' page. This information is held in an SQL database.

The C# part (relevant code only):

```
public partial class myaccount : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    public string username;
    public string birthday;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        username = (string)Session["user"];
        string sql = "select  * from users where username='" + username + "'";
        DataTable table = Eitan.ExecuteDataTable("database.mdf", sql);

        birthday = table.Rows[0]["birthday"].ToString();
    }
```

}

The relevant table row in HTML:

```
    <tr>
        <th>Birthday: </th>
        <td><%=birthday %></td>
    </tr>
```

Everything works fine except for the birthday value.. Its shows it as: 
    `7/8/1964 12:00:00 AM`

How can I get rid of the hour? Thanks!

Comment: What format do you wanna show it exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be advisable to use a [standard date and time format string](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1(v=vs.110).aspx), not the custom strings proposed so far, so that the date is formatted correctly for the user's culture. I would propose:

```
ToString("d")
```

which is the short date pattern. For example, using Mert's code with this pattern:

```
Convert.ToDateTime(table.Rows[0]["birthday"]).ToString("d");
```

today's date, 16 June 2015, would display as "6/16/2015" for `en-US` and "16/6/2015" for `fr-FR`.

More info on cultures in ASP.Net can be found on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bz9tc508(v=vs.140).aspx) but essentially it should work out of the box.

Answer (score 1):

```
  birthday = Convert.ToDateTime(table.Rows[0]["birthday"]).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
```